# Decode a file in WAV format

Tags: android, audio, fft, frequency

I have an audio file in WAV format. I suppose to decode the binary data encoded in the file. The data is encoded using Audio Frequency Shift-Keying (AFSK).
The technology is used for communication systems such as garage door opener.

I am beginner in that, so I am not sure which library should I use to decode the file which is encoded using AFSK.

Is there any library available for Android?

Answer (score 1):

You might want to try [android-fskmodem](https://github.com/cytecbg/android-fskmodem) or any other [FSK](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frequency-shift_keying#Audio_FSK) library.